# What word that describes the point when an event takes place?

Tags: synonyms, slang

An event (random event) takes place once it reaches that "certain point"...
It's something like, climax or maybe the top, so what's that called?
And thank you!

Comment: "[Apogee](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apogee)" fits the bill, so do "[peak](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/peak)" and "[pinnacle](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pinnacle)". We need more context and/or example sentences to determine the best one.

Comment: Something like apogee too, which is scientific, like mechanics...

Comment: I would probably use "peak" for more statistical and number related situations. (example: [graph peak](https://www.google.fr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=graph%20peak)).

Comment: The sequence can only occur once the ******** had been reached.
( has a tone like "ust" at the end )

Comment: Maybe you are looking for *cusp*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Tipping point](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/tipping-point) works in your example in the comments, even if it doesn't end in "ust". It encompasses the idea of circumstances changing enough to trigger the event. Apogee, peak and pinnacle all mean similar things, but don't necessarily imply triggering.

Comment: Thanks, that's another word added to my lexicon, also, I came across that word right now, it was Threshold, I know it doesn't have that "ust" ending, but it was the only thing I could think of...

Comment: @ZakariaTahiri Those two words indeed fit the sentence and are probably what you were looking for. However, for your information, they do not imply that it reached the peak (climax, top), but rather a specific point/limit, so maybe you'll want to edit your question accordingly, to match what you were really looking for, in order to be as accurate as possible.

Comment: Yeah, that was exactly my question!
(An event (random event) takes place once it reaches that "certain point")
Thanks once again!

Comment: *threshold* seems like the word...

Comment: The point of no return